# R: How to fit logistic regression with shared measurements?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, inference

I have 300 individuals who rated binary responses (1 or 0) on the same set of 500 questionnaires. I want to fit a logistic regression model to explore the association between the odds of rating (1 or 0) and demographic characteristics (gender, age group, race, and education level).

Currently, I am fitting glm() in R

```
glm(proportion ~ Gender + Age + Race + Education, data = data, weights=rep(500,300),family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Here, proportion = the proportion of questions where each person marked 1. For example, if an individual marked 1 for 200 questions and 0 for the remaining 300 questions, the proportion would be 0.4

For logistic regression, R's glm() usually takes binary variable (1 or 0) as a response variable. However, glm() also does take a proportion as a response variable if I specify 'weights' argument, which is the number of total trials, which is 500 (questionnaires) for everyone.

Is this the right approach? **I'm concerned that there might be an issue of non-independence of observations, given that everyone is given the same set of 500 questions.** The individuals are independent among each other, though.

Should I fit mixed models or anything else?

Comment: maybe a clustering to find the characteristic of person grouped by ranges of the odds rating that you describe?

Comment: Could you just include each person's 500 responses as 500 separate data points with a 0/1 valued response?